# FFMpeg UDP streaming - random split video effect

Tags: wcf, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mplayer

I'm trying to get a simple local preview of my webcam from an FFMpeg udp stream using an embedded Mplayer window. I can view the live stream using MPlayer but the image is unstable. I'm using the following FFMpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 640x480 -i video="Lenovo EasyCamera" -an -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuyv422 -r 15 udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

And this is the MPlayer command:

```
mplayer -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo fps=15:w=640:h=480:format=yuy2 -nofs -noquiet -identify -idle -slave -nomouseinput -framedrop -wid 1051072
```

Sometimes the stream image is OK, but intermittently the image tears randomly and this is how it looks (sorry, not enough rep for images in posts)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU3oj.jpg

I have tried with FFPlay to see if it's a problem with MPlayer, but I get the same result:

```
ffplay -s 640x480 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -f rawvideo -i udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa7jG.jpg

This effect is happening at random. If I stop and restart the video might be OK, or it may look like the above. Using aything other than udp and rawvideo adds a delay to the video stream, which I want to avoid.

The FFMpeg streaming guide suggest methods when you get packet loss, but as far as I'm aware I don't seem to be getting that.

I'm new to FFMpeg/Mplayer/video streaming and any help or thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're sending on udp which is lossy...ping me if you want to try an experimental patch to not burst packets :)